# Bluetooth SPP on iMac

Tags: macos, bluetooth, arduino

I'm am trying to get a Bluetooth module that implements the Serial Port Protocol to work with a recent iMac. What I would like is to pair the module, then open it as a serial port and read  data from the device, something like "cat /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB".

The problem I am having is that when I pair the module it shows as connected for about a minute and then reverts to a not connected state. While it is in the connected state, I am never able to find the appropriate device to read under /dev.

The kicker is that I had this working perfectly on a 7 year old iMac, which I sold when I bought a new one a few months ago. It's the same Bluetooth module running on an Arduino. The only thing that changed is the iMac.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? It feels like the OS connects and then doesn't know what to do and disconnects

Answer (score 0):

Apple removed a lot of Bluetooth support in their more recent models. My first MacBook Pro (early 2008 version) supported SyncML over Bluetooth so I could pair and sync my Motorola Razr address book with the Address app on the Mac.

Around Snow Leopard or Lion, all that support was removed. The hardware is still capable but the software supports much less than it used to. Bluetooth for audio is OK, Bluetooth for non-Apple devices beyond audio is very unpredictable. So it could just be that Apple removed the device support you were inadvertently relying on.

I suggest you have a look at the Mac's console and see what logging output there is when the connection is being negotiated. The Console is a surprisingly useful aid to diagnosing connection issues (when you consider how closed Apple are trying to make everything).